# Problema Hilos y Sockets

Tags: java, hilos

Hola estoy realizando un ejercicio que consiste en crear un programa que pueda enviar mensajes a un servidor mientras imprime por consola todos los archivos de determinada carpeta. A su vez el servidor debe ser capaz de recibir y también enviar mensajes al Cliente (todo esto mientras este último sigue imprimiendo por pantalla los archivos de la carpeta).
Esta aplicación la desarrollé utilizando Windows Builder para acelerar la parte de SWING.

El problema es que curiosamente cuando abro primero la aplicación del cliente (ubicada en la clase Interfaz) y luego la del Servidor, el botón BUSCAR del cliente no cumple su cometido (es decir no se imprimen por consola los archivos de dicha carpeta) todo lo demás anda.
Este botón funciona bien si

a) Sólo abro la aplicación Interfaz o

b) Abro primero Servidor y luego Interfaz.

He revisado el código y no entiendo el motivo. El programa consta de 4 clases  (Interfaz donde se carga la interfaz del Cliente y el método para enviar Mensajes al servidor / BusquedaDirectorio donde está el método para buscar todos los archivos de una carpeta / ClienteChat donde está el método para que el cliente reciba msjs del servidor/ Servidor donde está la interfaz y métodos del Servidor)

Código de Clase Interfaz

```
package usuario;
import funcionamiento.BusquedaDirectorio;
import funcionamiento.ClienteChat;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Interfaz {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField chat;
    private JButton btnBuscar;
    private JButton btnEnviar;
    private JTextArea chattotal;
    
    
    
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Interfaz window = new Interfaz();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Interfaz() {
        initialize();
       
        Runnable uno = new ClienteChat(chattotal);
        Thread hiloconstante = new Thread (uno);
        hiloconstante.start();
        
        
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 689, 466);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        btnBuscar = new JButton("BUSCAR EN \"C\"");
        btnBuscar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
                 Runnable c = new BusquedaDirectorio("C:\\Games");
                
                Thread hilo = new Thread(c);
                
                hilo.start(); 
                
            }
        });
        btnBuscar.setBounds(85, 230, 138, 46);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBuscar);
        
        btnEnviar = new JButton("Enviar");
        btnEnviar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
                Thread papa = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        
                    try {
                        Socket nuevosocket = new Socket("localhost", 7777);
                        DataOutputStream datos = new DataOutputStream(nuevosocket.getOutputStream());
                        datos.writeUTF(chat.getText());
                    
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                        
                    }
                });
            
            papa.start();
            }
        });
        btnEnviar.setBounds(419, 230, 117, 46);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnviar);
        
        chat = new JTextField();
        chat.setBounds(99, 99, 138, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(chat);
        chat.setColumns(10);
        
        chattotal = new JTextArea();
        chattotal.setBounds(293, 55, 310, 129);
        frame.getContentPane().add(chattotal);
    }
}
```

Código clase BusquedaDirectorio:

```
package funcionamiento;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class BusquedaDirectorio implements Runnable {

    
    String ruta;
    
    
   public   BusquedaDirectorio( String ruta) {
       
    
        this.ruta = ruta;
   
   }
    
    
    public void imprimir (String ruta) {
        
        Set <String> carpetas = new  HashSet<String>() ;
        boolean haycarpeta = false; 
        File ar = new File(ruta); 
        String dir [] = ar.list();
        System.out.println("\narchivos de : "+ ruta);
        
        for(int x = 0; x < dir.length ; x++) {              
            File b = new File(ruta+"\\"+dir[x]);    
            System.out.println("\n"+ dir[x]); 
            if(b.isDirectory()) { 
            System.out.print("  --> es carpeta");
            haycarpeta = true;
            carpetas.add(b.getName());          
            }
            }
    
        if (haycarpeta) {
            
        for(String a : carpetas) {
            
            System.out.println("\n entrando a carpeta : " + a);
            imprimir(ruta + "\\" + a);
            
        }
            
        }
    
    
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        imprimir(ruta);
    }
}
```

Código Cliente chat:

```
package funcionamiento;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ClienteChat implements Runnable {

JTextArea chattotal;
    
    public ClienteChat(JTextArea chattotal) {
        
        this.chattotal = chattotal; 
        
    }
    
    
    public void run() {
        
    try {
        ServerSocket missocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
        
        while(true) {
            
            Socket misocket = missocket.accept();
            DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(misocket.getInputStream());
            String datos = entrada.readUTF();
            chattotal.append(datos + "\n");
        }
        
    
    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    }
    
}
```

Clase Servidor:

```
package funcionamiento;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Servidor implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField texto;
    private JTextArea chatentero;
          

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Servidor window = new Servidor();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
     */
    

    /**
     * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
     */
    public Servidor() {
        
        initialize();
       Thread escucha = new Thread(this);
       escucha.start();
    }
    
    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 281, 436);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        texto = new JTextField();
        texto.setBounds(80, 276, 82, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(texto);
        texto.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton btnenviar = new JButton("Enviar");
        btnenviar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
                Thread enviarmsjservidor = new Thread (new Runnable() {

                
                    public void run() {
                        Socket enviarservidor;
                        try {
                            enviarservidor = new Socket("localhost",8888);
                        
                            DataOutputStream enviar = new DataOutputStream(enviarservidor.getOutputStream());
                            enviar.writeUTF(texto.getText());
                        
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }   
                    }
                });
                enviarmsjservidor.start();
            }
        });
        btnenviar.setBounds(80, 327, 82, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnenviar);
        
        chatentero = new JTextArea();
        chatentero.setBounds(27, 11, 204, 240);
        frame.getContentPane().add(chatentero);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
        
            ServerSocket missocket = new ServerSocket(7777);
            
            while(true) {
                
                Socket misocket = missocket.accept();
                DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(misocket.getInputStream());
                String datos = entrada.readUTF();
                chatentero.append(datos + "\n");
            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: He montado el proyecto y me lista por consola todo el directorio ejecutando primero el cliente (Interfaz) y después el servidor (Servidor), por lo que no sé que problema tienes. Podrías poner que error te da al pulsar el botón BUSCAR ?

Comment: hola no da ningún error. sencillamente no pasa absolutamente nada. es muy raro que a vos no te pase. Usaste Windows Builder también? el procedimiento sería ejecutar Interfaz, luego Servidor y luego apretar el botón. en ese orden no me funciona.

Comment: Estoy en Windows también y me lista por consola todo el directorio. El error debe estar en otra parte..